# Batch set time limit

Tags: firefox, batch-file, time, limit

i want to know is there a way to set time limit for step to finish in batch file.I have a batch that opens firefox and runs a script, and that script closes the firefox when finishes, but sometimes firefox procces stays open in task manager so batch won't continue with next step.If you didn't complitly understand me, here is an example what i want to make:

- Step 1:  START /WAIT firefox.exe (name of script, which closes
  firefox
  manually)
- wait 10 seconds to complete step 1, if not completed (if firefox is not closed) move to step 2

So, I am looking for any utility to launch each of the download command with
a specified time limit.
When the time limit is reached, end the current process automatically and
execute the next command.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add your current .bat?

Comment: START /WAIT firefox.exe -new-window (name of script)
START /WAIT firefox.exe -new-window (name of script2)

Answer (score 0):

how about opening firefox as a background process ?? so that it will not wait for firefox to close ? i hope this is what you eventually want

```
START /B firefox.exe
timeout /t 10 /nobreak
for /f "usebackq skip=1" %%p in (
   `wmic process where "name='firefox.exe'" get processid`) do (
if "%%p" GEQ "0" taskkill /PID %%p)
```

Comment: but i want it to wait for firefox to close and then continue to next step.

Comment: and if its not closed after 10s you want to kill it ??

Comment: its working fine ...   are you getting any error ?? @JackSparrow

Comment: It works just with START /B firefox.exe, but when i set START /B /W firefox.exe it won't work.

Comment: obviously !!! you are asking the bash to wait until it terminate then how will it execute next line ... you just want to wait for 10s right? that we are waiting using timeout , why do you want to add an /w flag again ??

Comment: look, i want to wait for firefox to finish, but if firefox has not finished in 10 seconds, i want it to terminate, ok?

Comment: see this is what the script will do now. will start firefox; wait for 10s; check if firefox is still running ? then kill it. this is what you want rt @JackSparrow

Comment: if its working please accept the answer ... so that its helpful for others with smiler question

Comment: it works after 10sec, but what if firefox closes after 5sec, i want it to go to next step, but it wait for 5 sec more.
What did you do, i can too, by this:
start firefox.exe
sleep 10
kill firefox.exe